# Stop image resizing in particular case - is that possible?

Tags: uploads, images

As for an ad management plugin, [I'm using WordPress' default media uploader](https://github.com/nanodesigns/ad-zonia/blob/master/ad-insert-edit-page.php). And WP Media Uploader automatically resizes images. But as the ad image is already resized (i.e.: 225 x 100px) it need not to resize into a new file for thumbnail (100 x 100px); because, that thumbnail is unnecessary for the site.

The cause I presented here, may be a very minute for such a solution, but in case, there is any other massive issue that, in such plugin we can stop the auto resizing with WP Media Uploader only on that plugin-uploads - I think that can be a good solution for any site.

**Is there a way to use WP Media Uploader, but can stop auto resizing images only onto that particular case uploads?**

But I also know that, plugin like *Regenerate Thumbnails* can override the rules and can do what I prohibited in my plugins for the site's space-savvy consumption.

Comment: To get you correctly, you do not want any thumbnails generated to save space? because otherwise you could just output the `full` size, and get the image you uploaded.

Comment: @fischi: You got the intention right. But as for implementation, not just thumbnails, it can be for any additional image sizes other than the original. I want to upload the full size and get the full size to be echoed, and only the full size to be stored (no other resizes) only on particular case - not global to a WP site.

Comment: Hm, if you use the default uploader I do not think that it is possible. But - why don't you just use a regular uploader, not one connected to the Media Library?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Filter Hook [`intermediate_image_sizes_advanced`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/intermediate_image_sizes_advanced) for control the resize function for different sizes. This hook get a array of different sizes and can control your resize with your requirements. Add your logic inside a plugin and remove sizes via this hook.

```
 // the hook in core
 $sizes = apply_filters( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', $sizes );
```

A small example to remove the resize for `medium`size.

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'fb_filter_image_sizes');
function fb_filter_image_sizes( $sizes) {

    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);

    return $sizes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bueltge. Please ensure me that, it won't effect the global WP 'medium' size, but only the 'medium' size in my plugin's Media Uploader...

Comment: Yes, I have understand, that you create a rule, that it only works on your plugin. Bur here in the question it is not readable, how we can identifier the plugin. Is your plugin a new page inside the backend of WP, than can you identifier with the function `get_current_screen()` and the hook from my answer run only on the right value inside the array of the return of this function. To understand `get_current_screen()` use the plugin Debug Objects and see his result on your page.

Comment: I've added the link of my plugin on github with the question. It has two screens - one to add the ad, and other to list the already added ad[s]. So you are suggesting we can use the filter using the specific `get_current_screen()`? If that works, I'll try later, it'd be good. Thanks.